# Command that copy files with given time stamp

Tags: awk, grep, regular-expression, cat, xargs

We need a command that copy files from current directory to another with given date.

```
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 276423 set 03 10:31 'event01.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 283861 set 03 10:34 'event02.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 280644 set 03 10:40 'event03.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 270234 set 03 03:26 'event04.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 293488 set 12 06:43 'event05.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 287417 set 12 07:48 'event06.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 280519 set 12 10:19 'event07.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 279631 set 12 19:43 'event08.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 286578 set 12 15:15 'event09.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 289830 set 12 18:41 'event10.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 305209 set 19 05:58 'event11.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 308275 set 19 06:20 'event12.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 275015 set 19 14:40 'event13.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 310610 set 19 15:40 'event14.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 311466 set 19 15:41 'event15.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 305241 set 19 15:51 'event16.csv'
-rw-r----- 1 schmidt schmidt 291699 set 19 15:56 'event17.csv'
```

For example, command should copy all files with "set 12" timestamp to directory `/home/12thsep/`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

You could be selecting by the date option in `find`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newerat '2019-09-19' ! -newerat '2019-09-20' -exec mv '{}' /home/12thsep \;
```

Answer (score 6):

You may use `find` with correct `mtime` arguments.
For example:

```
mkdir <dest_path> && find <source path> -mtime -X -a -mtime +Y -exec mv {} <dest_path>/ \;
```

Where X represent the "day after" and Y the "day before".
Note the use of `-a` to makes `find` use a AND between the two conditions specified.
Refer to [find manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for more details regarding syntax to use.

Comment: @Fixman answer looks better than mine. I didn't knew about `-newerat`...

Comment: FYI `-a` for AND is the default with `find`, so isn't needed.  you only need to specify a logical operator when you want to use OR (`-o`).    in other words, all predicates are AND-ed together unless you specify otherwise with `-o`.   You'll need parentheses (quoted or escaped on the shell command line, e.g. `\(` and `\)`) for nested or more complicated logic operators.

Comment: Thx for precisions @cas

Answer (score 5):

It may be done in following way:

```
ls -alF|grep "set 12" >> logxa00.txt

cat logxa00.txt| awk '{print $9}' > logxa01.txt

xargs -a logxa01.txt cp -p -t /home/12thsep/
```

Comment: Be careful with spaces and tabs in filenames. `awk` might print half a name only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out. Just list directory, grep the date stamp, and copy from each filename (argument $9) to your destination directory. The extra quotes in there catch files that have spaces in their name.

`ls -al | grep -i "set 12" | awk -F' ' '{ system("cp \"" $9 "\" /home/12thsep") }'`

Should be easy to modify in the future for other applications.